# Why can we calculate the supremum of operator norm over unit circle?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, linear-transformations, supremum-and-infimum

I know that to check whether a linear operator is continuous or not we have to check if the operator norm is bounded. $$T: V\to W$$,

$$\vert\vert \ T \vert\vert= \sup_{f \in V}\frac{\vert\vert \ Tf \vert\vert}{\vert\vert \ f \vert\vert} $$

There is just one thing I do not understand. I see in some solutions that they calculate the supremum over unit circle; ( $\vert\vert \ f \vert\vert=1$)

$$\vert\vert \ T \vert\vert= \sup_{\vert\vert \ f \vert\vert=1} \vert\vert \ Tf \vert\vert$$

When and why are they equivalent? Why are we allowed to evaluate the supremum only on a unit circle?

Thanks.

Comment: because it is a linear operator so knowing $T [x] $ for any $||x|| = 1$ allows us to compute $T [y] = ||y|| T [y/||y||]  $ for any $y$

Comment: @user1952009: That's an answer, isn't it?

Comment: this should also prove that a linear operator is bounded iff it is uniformely continuous at $0$